# trying to get a regex match in javascript with certain letter followed by any number

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a regular expression to work, but it isn't. It must be a small thing, but I could use some help. I tried using the regex tester at https://regex101.com/ and it said I wasn't doing it right, but it isn't working in my code.

I want to look at a string and see if there's a match for:

space letter v or V no space number between 0 and 9 space letter t or T no space number between 0 and 9 space

Example: " v5 t2 " or " V5 T2 "

Here's javascript/jquery:

```
if (mystring.indexOf(/v[0-9] t[0-9]/i) > -1) {
    console.log("found!");
} else {
    console.log("not found!");
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please? I'm new to regular expressions.

Comment: `indexOf` doesn't work with regex. Use `match` or `exec` or `test`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexOf` doesn't accept a regular expression, it accepts a string. So your regex is converted to string, which then doesn't match.

If you want to check for a match, use `RegExp#test`:

```
if (/v[0-9] t[0-9]/i.test(mystring)) {
    // Yes
} else {
    // No
}
```

Note that looks anywhere in the string.

Also note that `[0-9]` is `\d`, so the regex could be `/v\d t\d/i`.

```js
var mystring = "foo V5 T7 bar";
if (/v\d t\d/i.test(mystring)) {
    console.log("found!");
} else {
    console.log("not found!");
}
```

**If** you needed to know *where* the match occurred, you'd use `String#match` or `RegExp#exec` instead, and look at the `index` property of the result:

```js
var mystring = "foo V5 T7 bar";
var match = /v\d t\d/i.exec(mystring);
if (match) {
    console.log("Found at " + match.index);
} else {
    console.log("Not found");
}
```

Comment: In this case, you need `match` instead of test (which only returns true/false for match/not match): `'foo V5 T7 bar'.match(/v\d t\d/i)` which yields `["V5 T7", index: 4, input: "foo V5 T7 bar"]` (with index 0 being the matched part of the string).

Comment: @SVSchmidt: No, you don't need `match` just to check **if** there's a match. That's exactly what `test` is for.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm aware of that, as I'm saying in the first sentence. I don't know if the comment above mine was edited, but I answered to the question "what if I need the actual match?".

Comment: @SVSchmidt: Ah! Yes, they must have edited (it has the edit mark on it).